# ridgepoleでforeign_keyをto_tableと別名のcolumn_nameで生成する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

私はrails(6.0.3.1)上でridgepole(0.8.7)を使っています。

以下のようなテーブルがあります。

[image]

このとき、friend_idにHumanテーブルからHumanテーブルへのforeign_keyを貼りたいのですがどうすればいいかわかりません。
https://github.com/winebarrel/ridgepole#foreign-key には、from_table, to_table, fk成約名しか引数にとってないように見えます。

```
create table 略 |t|
  t.foreign_key 略 # ←これも試しに書いてみたが動かなかった(※rails_migrationには存在する)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

columnオプションで出来ました。

```rb
add_foreign_key "humen", "humen", column: "friend_id"
```

---

ソース

公式の返答
https://github.com/winebarrel/ridgepole/issues/300#issuecomment-641740617

> The syntax of ridgepole basically follows the Rails migration.
>   Please refer to the Rails documentation.

そしてrailsのAPI
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-foreign_key

Comment: https://github.com/winebarrel/ridgepole/issues/300 にて公式に質問中

Comment: issueで回答をもらったので、回答を編集し、情報ソースを追記しました。